# Was or Were for this past year?

Tags: grammar

```
If 2020 were a school year, we'd have to repeat it.
```

or

```
If 2020 was a school year, we'd have to repeat it.
```

Personally, I personally `was` is the way to go here. I'd appreciate being corrected if I'm wring here.

Comment: The first one is clearly in the subjunctive. The second one could be either in the subjunctive or in the indicative, and to find out which of the two it is, the reader has to read the entire rest of the sentence. Until then they'll assume that it's probably the indicative, because it's way more common. Only to then be proven wrong and have to go back and re-parse the sentence. So the question is really: do you care for your readers wasting their time, or do you care for your readers immediately understanding you.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I can think of some ways of making the *was* version indicative, but I'd say that given that the sentence starts with ***if***, it's the subjunctive that's actually far more common in this case.